# What does 'bespoken' signify, as opposed to 'bespoke'?

Tags: word-usage, transatlantic-differences

The verb *bespeak* admits two past participles: *bespoke* and  *bespoken*. I am interested in the attributive usage of these terms.

A *bespoke suit* is one tailored to please and to fit a particular customer. Occasionally, *bespoken* is used in the same sense. I am puzzled by the difference. Personally I find *bespoken* to be rarer, and Google seems to concur.

My question is, whether the two are interchangeable, or whether a preference of one over the other is significant in terms of register, region, or whether there is actually a nuance in meaning.

Comment: I’ve never heard of a *bespoken suit*. Neither has [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bespoken+suit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)

Comment: @Jim Google gives quite a few hits. Besides, there's the company http://www.bespokennewyork.com. It appears to be owned by a British expat. It made me wonder whether it is significant to use 'bespoken'.

Comment: ***They*** probably think it’s significant to use *bespoken*.  I’d never do it though.

Comment: *Bespoke* (and perhaps *bespoken*) is primarily British English. It is rarely used in American English. It is apparently [also not very common in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bespoke%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbespoke%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbespoke%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbespoke%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0). (I added tag `British English`.) My impression is that it is used fairly often by English speakers from India, but I have no citation for that.

Comment: Adding new tags, such as _British English_ or _transatlantic differences_, amounts to assuming a lot. Do you actualy  **know** that the difference, if any,  rests in British vs. US usage?

Comment: @anemone -          Bespoken NewYork is a brand. The reason why they used it is more a marketing issue rather than a  linguistic one.

Comment: @JOSH Yes, it is marketing. Absolutely. But that's the point! The marketing would not work without the language assumptions.

Comment: It's important to note that "bespoke" was not heard in the US prior to maybe 20 years ago (except perhaps in circles where Britishisms were popular).  The term in the US was "tailored", or perhaps "custom made".  Writing for a US audience one should be careful to avoid using the term outside of it's tailoring context, except perhaps in a figurative sense.  And probably avoid "bespeak" entirely, as your listener will not easily be able to tell if you're speaking in a tailoring sense or in the sense of "suggest".

Comment: @HotLicks - Although “bespoke development” is a fairly common  term in the software field of late.

Comment: @anemone - yes, but marketing decisions follow  trends that may have little to do with current or past meanings of words. It may be a question of assonance for instance. We don't know. The use of "bespoken" in a brand doesn't tell us much about a possible current usage.

Comment: @Jim - Only since about 1985-90.  Ngram is zero in 1979.

Comment: @HotLicks - Agree.  ‘85-90 is actually earlier than I would have guessed.

Comment: I'm guessing that "bespoke" experienced a major jump in 2014 with the movie *Kingsman*.

Comment: @Jim - I'll note that I've been in the computer biz since 1972, and only first heard the term "bespoke development" maybe 3 years ago.

Comment: Per the OED, **bespoke** is the past tense of the verb **bespeak** (along with the archaic **bespake**), and **bespoke** and **bespoken** are both past participle. "For other forms, see **speak *n.***" Thus: *I love my bespoke suits. I **bespoke**  a dozen last year, but alas I've only **bespoken** two so far this year. If my Christmas bonus comes through, I'm going to **bespeak** two more.*

Comment: @1006a Really? Well I consulted dictionaries. They do not answer the question. I cannot see how your comment is pertinent.

Comment: @anemone - what is unclear here is your question. If you are asking if there is a revival anywhere of the term bespoken , meaning bespoke, the answer in NO. A marketing term does not necessarily have clear linguistic implications.

Comment: @JOSH As `bespoken' is occasionally used, I ask about the possible distinction between the two words. I do not think it can be waved aside as just a marketing term.

Comment: @anemone - there is actually no evidence of this resurgent usage, apart from some rare instances which are not enough to make any clear inference. The fact that bespoken was the original spelling of beskope may have somehow influenced marketing people, or it is just a play on "spoken."

Comment: With regard to sartorial matters and the British, bespoke tailoring meant Savile Row in London, those Master Tailors & Cutters who took their skills to the rest of the UK and sometimes overseas as well. You'd start off on the wrong foot if you let it be known to your bespoke tailor that you weren't aware of the difference between custom tailoring of the USA and the traditions of London's Savile Row.

Comment: @PeterPoint You are suggesting, as others have before, that the difference is regional, if I understand correctly. In tailoring and in advertising? Well I'm not so sure (about the linguistic side). Is there some evidence for that? Anyway, _bespoken_ is not as rare as some users here try to argue, I think. Hence the question.

Comment: @anemone My previous comment was confined to my understanding (personal experience) of  the 'bespoke' tailoring traditions of Savile Row in London, as compared to the 'custom' tailoring traditions of the US. I didn't dare to broach the other part of the OP ('bespoken') which looks and sounds rather biblical (King James edition) or 19th century Dickensian to my layman's eyes and ears. Consequently I confined my response to a half-baked comment rather than a full-on answer. Salutations.

Answer (score 1):

Bespoken appears to be the original term  before "bespoke" was used to mean custom-made. Its usage in that sense is now archaic and rare:

***[Bespoke](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bespoke)*** (adj.):

> - "custom or custom-made, made to order," of goods, as distinguished from ready-made, 1755, ***the same sense found earlier in bespoken (c. 1600), past participle of bespeak***, in a sense of "to speak for, to arrange beforehand," a sense attested in bespeak from 1580s. Now usually of tailored suits.

Etymonline

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bespoken%2Cbespoke&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbespoken%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbespoke%3B%2Cc0) *bespoke vs bespoken*

Comment: Of course, "bespeak", in all it's verb forms, also means "indicate" *The road bespoke money.*  There are many ways this word could be used in a confusing fashion.

Answer (score 0):

A suit is "bespoke" as opposed to "tailored" or "custom made" but that doesn't mean any of them is "bespoken…”

I think a “bespoke” suit is one that *will be spoken about* before completion, in the sense of discussing all the little details. It hasn’t yet been stitched, so it can’t be seen on the hanger.

I think a “bespoken” suit is one that *has been spoken for* already, in the sense of having been reserved. It might be hanging on display but it’s already been sold.

I thought “bespoken” might also be heard in furniture showrooms or on garage forecourts and that rather obviously, the other main use of that tense was in marriage contracts: a man, more usually a woman “bespoken” was a more poetic, romantic or more formal, albeit  rather archaic option for the modern “spoken for” but pride goeth before a fall…

Asking Google for examples revealed “bespoken” to be so obscure, the only useful hit I got was from an anthropological study of the African Bemba, *Seven Tribes of British Central Africa*, by Elizabeth Colson, ‎Max Gluckman (1951)

On marriage customs of the Nyakyusa of South-Western Tangankyika we read that “A girl who is bespoken in infancy does not, ideally, go to live altogether with her husband till after she has reached puberty...”

In the sense of software development, I certainly heard the term “bespoke software” along with "bespoke solutions" in daily use for years among developers, vendors and users before, for instance, Apple’s Lisa came out in 1983 or the Edsel Apple III in 1980 though perhaps not before the Apple II in 1977.